# Function That Sums All Elements in List Up to But Not Including The First Even Number

Tags: python, list, if-statement, element, addition

I'm trying to write a python function that will sum up all of the elements in a list up to but not including the first even number. The function needs to pass the following tests:

```
from test import testEqual

testEqual(sum_of_initial_odds([1,3,1,4,3,8]), 5)
testEqual(sum_of_initial_odds([6,1,3,5,7]), 0)
testEqual(sum_of_initial_odds([1, -7, 10, 23]), -6)
testEqual(sum_of_initial_odds(range(1,555,2)), 76729)
```

I tried the following:

```
import random

lst = []
def sum_of_initial_odds(nums):
    sum = 0
#test if element is odd number - if it's odd, add it to the previous integer
    for i in lst:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            sum = sum + i
        return sum
#test if element is even number - if it's even, don't include it and break code
        else: 
            if i % 2 == 0:
        break:
```

I'm currently getting a parse error:

```
ParseError: bad input on line 11
```

which is the line:

```
else:
```

How else can I write this code so that it adds the elements in a list, but doesn't include the first even number, without getting Parse errors?

Comment: `return sum` is indented incorrectly, as is `break:` (which, while we're at it, should not have a colon).

Comment: I tried moving back the indentation by four spaces twice, both times I got the same result.

Comment: It needs more, not less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems:

1. Indentations, which others have already mentioned
2. You return **sum** the first time you hit an odd number; this is *so* not what you want.
3. You ignore the input parameter **nums** and work with the empty global **lst**.
4. Your lowest **if** is redundant: you already *know* you have an even number when you get here.

In general, stuff partial results into local variables; have a single **return** at the bottom of your routine.

```
import random

def sum_of_initial_odds(lst):
    sum = 0
#test if element is odd number - if it's odd, add it to the previous integer
    for i in lst:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            sum = sum + i
#test if element is even number - if it's even, don't include it and break code
        else: 
            break

    return sum

print sum_of_initial_odds([1,3,1,4,3,8]) == 5
print sum_of_initial_odds([6,1,3,5,7]) == 0
print sum_of_initial_odds([1, -7, 10, 23]) == -6
print sum_of_initial_odds(range(1,555,2)) == 76729
```

THe output from this is four **True** values.

Comment: Your explanation is making sense so far, but I'm still getting a name error: "NameError: name 'lst' is not defined on line 6"

Comment: Did you remember to change the name of the function parameter from **nums** to **lst** ?

Comment: That was probably the problem!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this very easily using [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> sum(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x % 2 == 1, [1,3,1,4,3,8]))
5
```

`takewhile` will yield elements from the given sequence while the predicate `x % 2 == 1` is `True`, i.e. it will get you all numbers up to the first even one. And `sum`, well, sums those values.

Comment: Cool, I was looking for the python version of this, in Scala it is `Seq(1,3,1,4,3,8).takeWhile(_ % 2 == 1).foldLeft(0)(_+_)`

Comment: @evan058 I don't know Scala, but I would hope that instead of `foldLeft(0)(_+_)` you can just say `sum` or so...

Comment: Ha, yeah, this works too: `Seq(2,1,3,1,4,3,8).takeWhile(_ % 2 == 1).sum
`. Classic over complication (though I am sure that is how sum is defined)

Comment: [That is how it is defined](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L216). Ok, done hijacking this python stuff w/ my scala nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use

```
def sum(numbers):
    sum = 0
    for number in numbers:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            break
        else:
            sum += number
    return sum
```

And test using the `asset` statement which is a specialized form of `raise` statement
The advantage is that it throws `AssertionError` only when `__debug__` is true thus avoiding throwing exception in production.

```
assert sum([1,3,1,4,3,8]) == 5 , "Your message if assertion fails"
```

You can turn off `__debug__` by

- Start interactive mode with `python -O`
- Setting variable `PYTHONOPTIMIZE` to `True`